# How to re-use a Theorem's number when repeating it for convenience

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, copy-paste

I want to have an appendix with a theorem's proof. The theorem appears in the main body of the document, and I would like to have it replicated in the appendix as well for convenience.

If I simply copy the original theorem environment, it is rendered in the appendix with a new number. I would like to use the same original number through `\ref`. What is the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Bonus points: it would be even better to somehow manage an entire copy of the theorem without actually repeating the source code for it, but referencing the first occurrence. This way, if I decide to change details in the theorem, they would be automatically reflected in the appendix's copy. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: this might help:: [How do you reprint a theorem, proposition, etc. in its entirety?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348867/579)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the `restatable` environment from `thmtools` + `thmrestate`. See details and explanations in §1.4, *Repeating theorems* of the documentation of `thmtools`. Note this package cooperates with `amsthm` as well as `ntheorem`.

The example in the documentation goes as follows: first declare your theorem environment:

```
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\declaretheorem{theorem}
\begin{restatable}[Euclid]{theorem}{firsteuclid}
\label{thm:euclid}%
For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p’>p$.
In particular, the list of primes,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
2,3,45,7,\dots
\end{equation}
is infinite.
\end{restatable}
```

The last argument of the `restatable` environment is the name of the command which will be used to restate the theorem:

`\firsteuclid`, or the starred version: `\firsteuclid*`, which reproduces the numbering of the original version.