# how can I put the same proposition in the main body and also in the appendix?

Tags: appendix

I would like to put a proposition (say Proposition 4) in the main body without the proof, and in the meanwhile also put the same Proposition number with the same statement in the appendix with the proof. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: See the `thmtools`package documentation, §1.4 Repeating theorems, pp. 6-7.

Comment: thank you, but I still do not know how to do... I'm a green hand. Could you please give a full example?

Comment: Likely duplicate: [How do you reprint a theorem, proposition, etc. in its entirety?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348867)  (By the way, @Bernard, this is yours; see [Often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419) in the meta queue.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I knew I had posted on the subject but wasn't able to find it using a significant sentence from the code, that's why I re-posted it.

Comment: @Bernard -- Oh, that wasn't meant as a criticism.  I know it's often wretchedly hard to find something one knows is there.  That's why, when I find a really good answer, I usually add it to that collection, so it can be found again.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I didn't take it as such, Milady. Just wanted to explain I tried  – fruitlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an answer of mine on this site, so I'll reproduce its code here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
 \declaretheorem[name=Proposition]{proposition}

\begin{document}

 \begin{restatable}{proposition}{Firstprop}
   This is a proposition.
 \end{restatable}

\appendix
\section{Proofs}
\Firstprop*
  \begin{proof}
  add my proof to this part \qedhere
\end{proof}

\section{More results}
\begin{proposition}
  This is another proposition.
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I first nest a proposition in a `restatable` environment, defined by the `thm-restate` package. To the second argument of the environment (`Firstprop`) is associated a `\Firstprop*` command, whch restates the proposition where it is used.

Comment: Thank you so much Bernard, indeed it works! And it is very simple, without need of copying the statement of propositions in the appendix, which is very convenient!  A matter I encountered in this way was that all propositions are ordered with Proposition 1, Proposition 2, .... In the current setting, Proposition 4 is following Definition 4.1. But it is supposed to be Proposition 4.2, instead of Proposition 4. I spent a lot of time fixing this, but failed. Do you know how to fix the problem? Thanks again.

Comment: A minimal compilable code would be necessary to try  understanding  what happens. Could you post one?